# Gaussian Integrals with Grassmann Variables - a question

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

A Gaussian integral with Grassmann variables can be written as follows:
$$\int\prod_{i=1}^n (d\vartheta_i\,d\bar{\vartheta}_i)\; \exp{\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n \bar{\vartheta}_i\,a_{ij}\,\vartheta_j\right)}$$
The book I'm studying on goes on expanding the integrand at the following manner:
$$\exp{\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^n \bar{\vartheta}_i\,a_{ij}\,\vartheta_j\right)} = \prod_{i=1}^n \exp{\left(\bar{\vartheta}_i \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\,\vartheta_j\right)} = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\bar{\vartheta}_i \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\,\vartheta_j\right)$$
While I'm able to understande the first passage, I really can't figure out the last one; any help would be much apprecited!

EDIT: @Nox's comment helped me figure out that it's just a Taylor expansion (and it gives that result because $\vartheta_i \vartheta_i = 0$, being a Grassmann variable.

Comment: Hint: Taylor series. Second hint: $\theta_i\theta_i=?$

Comment: It's irrelevant whether the argument is small c.f https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition